# Python: A list of links to pdf file in excel spreadsheet. How do I download and convert them to text files?

Tags: python, python-requests, download

I have a spreadsheet with a column named "address" that has a list of links to files. The format of the link goes something like this: "https://xxxx.org/page/showpdf?path=XXX.0001.NAME%20P.%LASTNAME.pdf&title=XXX.0001.NAME%20P.%20GALLEY"
When I click the link, after loading for a while, it opens up a pdf file on the internet. I am trying to accomplish two things using Python:

1. download each pdf file on the list and
2. convert it to text file(.txt).

I am stuck on the very first step. I've tried the following code but it downloaded empty/unreadable pdf files.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_excel("topic.xlsx")
urls = df["address"].tolist()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    with open("{}_{}_{}.pdf".format(row.topic, row.topic_name, row.number), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(row["address"]).content)
```